# Client side text search on large corpus

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, client-side, client-side-scripting

I have a large collection of text files (about 6000, 100MB total) and I would like to implement a web application to perform search on it. For a number of reasons I need it to be a purely client-side solution. I have tried the JS library LunrJS but the created index file is monolithic and too large for any practical client-side usage (over 100 MB in size). Are there any more efficient libraries or alternative methods?

Comment: Have you looked at `indexedDB`?

Comment: I have looked at your suggestion, could you be a bit more specific? I'd like the solution to be implemented as a set of files that could be easily transferred server to server (I was not looking forward to set a server-side database)

Comment: It was not a suggestion, I'm just curious if it fits your needs.